# How to remove a card's inner padding in flutter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

I have placed a bookmark icon inside a card, but am unable to remove the inner padding of the card. I would like to have the bookmark icon stick to the border of the card. How should I do it?

I have aligned the icon to "topRight", but it can't help.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? I can't understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 59):

I just want to leave a full code removing the default margin to make it clear

```
Card(
  margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
  ),
  elevation: 4,
  child: Image.network(
    model.item.image,
    width: 20,
    height: 200,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

Answer (score 18):

Can you try setting the **margin** property of card to **EdgeInsets.zero**

Comment: am not understanding this. Question for removing the padding and answer is to apply zero margin and how it removes inner padding !!

Comment: the question is about padding not margin

Answer (score 4):

The Card widget has Padding by default. If this is not the desired behavior you could implement your own widget using Container that looks like a Card

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your `Card` into a `MediaQuery.removePadding` or `MediaQuery.removeViewPadding` or `MediaQuery.removeViewInsets`. It works for all widgets with default padding/inner spacing and you can select the specific padding you want to remove (`top`, `bottom`, `right` or `left`):

```dart
MediaQuery.removeViewInsets(
  removeRight: true,
  removeLeft: true,
  removeTop: true,
  removeBottom: true,
  context: context,
  child: Card(...),
)
```